# wsdl + svutil

Tags: java, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I need to resolve a pcakage import in java.. but the package was not present.. Then i later found that I have to use some wsdl file to genrate the pacakage.. I have a link fo that wsdl file.. How to use svcutil to generate that pacakage/ resolve the imported pacakage...

```
D:\Profiles\pdk473\Desktop>svcutil  /t:metadata http://service/metadataEndpoint

SvcUtil V02.04.00cpp  Joe Richards (joe@joeware.net) June 2005

Usage:
 SvcUtil [machine\]service [action]

   machine         Machine to process services on
   service         Key/Display Name of service to view/manipulate
                   . for list of available services
   action          Action to perform
        STOP       Stop Service
        START      Start Service
        PAUSE      Pause Service
        RESUME     Resume Service
        VIEW       View Service
        VIEWX      Extended View Service


 This software is Freeware. Use it as you wish at your own risk.
 If you have improvement ideas, bugs, or just wish to say Hi, I
 receive email 24x7 and read it in a semi-regular timeframe.
 You can usually find me at joe@joeware.net
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that Microsoft's `svcutil` is generating Java code?  From what I can tell it's going to generate you some C++ code, which won't help much.

When I've needed to generate Java stubs from WSDL in the past, I've used the Axis framework's [wsdl2java](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL).  The use is straightforward and explained in the linked document.

Answer (score 0):

svcutil cannot generate java code. Can only create C#, C++, and VB code.